# Google Adsense for legally purchased domain + localhost

Tags: adsense

I'm going to register for Google Adsense but there is single point that needs to be clear before submitting my application to Google.

I'm having a website running on localhost through a legally purchased domain name http://www.example.com so my question is very simple. Is my application for google adsense eligible since the hosting is localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some conditions, if you'r connected to Internet then the ads may able to show over there on your Localhost. In case of disconnection with Internet ads will not appear at all because Ads coding is Part of Google Adsense Servers which will be disconnected without internet.

Answer is right if i get your point. :)